# How to create custom the featured product,Best saler product and new arival product with tabs on home of magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax

I want to add the Featured product,Best Seller and New arrival in tab format. Means when I click on featured product the featured product slider get display, when click on best seller product then best seller product get display.Please can anyone suggest me suitable solution for it. Because I am new user of Magento. Should I need to create the custom extension. If yes then please give me steps to be followed.

Comment: what do you mean by featured product?

Comment: Featured product is special type of category product which I want to show on Home page.

Comment: fine then you have to create a category.and retrieve product collection according to that category id.I will post you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your product collection as you want in home home page

For **Featured Products**

Create you category(Featured Product) from back end and use that id in the collection.
You can use your featured category id instead of **#yourid**

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', '#yourid')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize(6);
    foreach ($productsCollection as $product):
        $_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
```

For **Latest Products**

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize(6);
    foreach ($productsCollection as $product):
     $_product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
       **What ever prodcut details you want to view**
    endforeach;
```

For **Most Viewed Prodcuts**

```
<?php 
    $productCount_mostviewd = 15; 
    // store ID
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();       
    // get most viewed products for current category
    $products_mostviewd = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount()
        ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::registry('current_category'))
        ->setPageSize($productCount_mostviewd); 
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
            ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products_mostviewd);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
            ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products_mostviewd);
foreach ($products_mostviewd as $product): $_product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());?>
endforeach;
```

For **Best Selling Products**

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $products->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);
    $this->setProductCollection($products);
```

You can use this collection.
notice that setPageSize(5) is help retrieve  n number of products in your collection.

Comment: For adding above code should I follow the steps for creating custom module..?http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643, as I m new user of Magento

Comment: Please can you text me here which steps should I follow..if me not wrong..

Comment: i just suggest you the algorithms for getting the product collection for each category(featured, latest, best selling).You can customize the home page listing with this algorithms by adding any slider or tabs according to your need.For the home page listing purpose no need to create any modules.

Comment: you can get idea from https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/

Comment: I am adding the bestseller product as per link :https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/  on home page it just showing lable Bestseller but not displaying product list below that..how should I overcome this..?

Comment: do you complete any purchase using your website?

Comment: No not purchase any thing..just adding custom code.

Comment: u have to purchase some products, then only u can retrieve the best selling product.use cash on delivery option for checkout.
Or try some code for most viewed product instead of best selling.

Comment: I following cash on delivery method to purchase product still it not showing best selling product on home page.

Comment: That entire block is not appear or only the products are not retrieve?
 Pls try make visible the block first.then try to get a product collection for some specific category.

Comment: @Ashwini any update?

Comment: Sir not working..

Comment: no idea about your approach and all, so unable to help you,but these are the codes for your needs once you make it possible to view the block first.Or you can try for the latest product first.

Comment: Thanks sir for your kind help..I will again try to solve it step by step way.